# Send # as keystroke with auto hotkey

Tags: autohotkey

We are working on a AHK program where we need to send # as a keystroke.
We already tried `Send, #` but doesnt work.

Couldnt find the right keystroke in the list: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm

Full program looks like this:

```
^q::
Send,
(
^f
#
)
```

Comment: `#::Send`. See [How is hash (#) key represented in AutoHotKey? - Ask for Help - AutoHotkey Community](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/32557-how-is-hash-key-represented-in-autohotkey/)

Answer (score 1):

> When the **[Send command](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm)** or Hotstrings are used in their default
> (non-raw) mode, **characters such as {}^!+# have special meaning**.
>
> Therefore, **to use them literally in these cases, enclose them in
> braces.** For example: Send {^}{!}{{}.

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/misc/EscapeChar.htm#Remarks

```
Send {#}
```

or ([raw mode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/Send.htm#Raw)):

```
Send {Raw}#
```

or ([Text mode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/Send.htm#Text)):

```
Send {Text}#
```